# How to access file binary with Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to process a CSV file from within App Maker. I need to read the contents of the file and process it so that I can insert the correct data into the database. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use Utilities.parseCsv to do this. This will render the data in a 2D array which you can use array[0] to access your header row if you have any and then array[0][0] to access your individual headers, then you can loop over the array starting with the first row that contains data like array[1] if you have a header row.

Comment: That's great, however I am looking for a more generalized way to access the binary data of a file within App Maker

Comment: There’s also file.getBlob().getDataAsString(). I think you will be of a lot better to do a search on Google Apps Script along with what you are trying to do with your data. App Maker runs on GAS so keep that in mind.